# Basic flow of control in Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets, control-flow

I've made a simple client server program in Java using Socket Programming but I'm unable to understand the basic flow of control of the program.

**Client file**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException{
      1. System.out.println("CLIENT:  "+"client main method started");

      2. Socket s=new Socket("localhost",23456);

      3. BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

      4. br.write("CLIENT:  "+"here comes the client message");

      5.br.flush();

    }
```

**Server File**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        11. System.out.println("Server is started");

        12. ServerSocket ser=new ServerSocket(23456);

        13. Socket s=ser.accept();

        14. System.out.println("SERVER: "+"Server is now accepting connections");

        15. System.out.println("SERVER: "+"client connected");

        16. BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        17. String str=br.readLine();

        18. System.out.println("SERVER: "+"Client Message: "+str);
    }
```

It would be really helpful if someone could please explain me the flow of the program with the help of LINE NUMBERS i.e. by statement by statement. 
P.S - Line number for server file starts with 11, just for sake of the convenience.
Thanks.

Comment: (1) Please provide full self-contained code snippets so that people answering can be able to test what they are saying is valid.

Comment: First:  11,12,13,14 (at this moment, client could connect).  Second: 1,2,3,4,5 (client send information to server).  Third:  15,16,17,18 (server reads client information and do something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I understand it, the regular flow of any server/client application is:

1. The server socket is established.
2. The server is listening on port 23456 on incoming connections(blocking wait). Once it unblocks, the connection request that unblocked it is stored inside a Socket.
3. The client sends a message to the server via a Socket, which the server immediatly stores when it unblocks.
4. The server wakes up because it got a message (unblocks), and the Socket connection is established.
5. The server reads the message from the client. (If you skip this step, the client typically gets confused). This is done via the Socket accepted.
6. The server generates a response to the client and sends it, through a write stream of the Socket accepted.
7. The server closes the output stream(of the Socket accepted) to indicate end of communication. (This is required).

For a related example:

Here is a relatively simple (not really but I tried to be as explicit as I could) self contained web server that listens on port 80. Once you run it, go to http://127.0.0.1:80 to see the default page. In this program, the client is your web browser(or any other program that tries to listen on localhost 80)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import jserv.*;

public class JavaServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket conn = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        String msg = null;
        ArrayList<String> tcp_get = null;

        System.out.println("server> Starting!");

        server = new ServerSocket(80);         

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("server> Waiting on a connection.");

            conn = server.accept();

            System.out.println("server> Obtaining io handles.");

            out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), true);           
            in = new BufferedReader (
                new InputStreamReader (
                    conn.getInputStream()
                )
            );

            System.out.println("server> We get signal.");

            while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("        " + msg);

                /* done if empty line or null. */
                if (msg.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("-- all client info is read --");
                    break;
                }

                /* additional protocol handling. */
                if (msg.startsWith("GET")) {
                    tcp_get = get_decode(msg);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("server> sending a message to client.");        

            /* send the HTML data. acknowledge? */
            /* header */
            out.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
            out.write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
            out.write("\r\n");

            /* response division. */
            System.out.println("tcp_get empty: " + tcp_get.isEmpty());
            if (!tcp_get.isEmpty()) {
                String page = tcp_get.get(0);

                /* we have a page request. */
                if (isValidPage(page)) {
                    File f = new File(page);

                    try {
                        Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f));
                        String s;

                        while ((s = br.nextLine()) != null) {
                            out.write(s + "\r\n");
                        }

                        br.close();

                        out.write("\r\n");
                        System.out.println("server> closing stream.");        
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                
                        out.write("<p>ERROR 404!</p>\r\n");
                        out.write("\r\n");
                        System.out.println("sent default message.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
                /* once the stream is closed, the client will receive the data."); */
            } else {
                out.write("<p>Welcome to the default page!</p>\r\n");
                out.write("\r\n");
            }
            out.close();

            System.out.println("server> end of communication.");        
        }
    }

    private static boolean isValidPage(String page)
    {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\.html");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(page);

        return mat.matches();
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> get_decode(String get) 
    {
        ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern pat;
        Matcher mat;
        String page;

        String page_pattern = "\\w+\\.html";
        String arg_pattern = "\\w+=\\w+";
        String gt = get.replaceFirst(page_pattern, "");       

        /* obtain the page name. */        
        pat = Pattern.compile(page_pattern);
        mat = pat.matcher(get);

        if (!mat.find()) {
            System.out.println("decode> GET invalid.");    
            return tmp;
        } else {
            page = mat.group();
            System.out.println("GET requests " + page);            
            tmp.add(page);
        }

        /* strip name from get. */
        gt = get.replaceFirst(page_pattern, "");        

        /* obtain the arguments. */
        pat = Pattern.compile(arg_pattern);
        mat = pat.matcher(gt);

        while (mat.find()) {
            System.out.println("argument: " + mat.group());
            tmp.add(mat.group());
        }        

        return tmp;
    }
}
```

In response to your actual code, please look back at this code with respect to the 7 points I listed.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {        
        System.out.println("client> started.");
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 23456);
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        // all messages must end with two linefeeds.
        br.write("hello, world!\n\n");
        // two linefeeds with no messages indicates end.
        br.write("\n\n");

        // see part 7. closing the stream flushes the output.
        br.close();
    }
}

class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ser = null;
        Socket s = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String str = null;

        System.out.println("server> started");
        ser = new ServerSocket(23456);
        s = ser.accept();
        System.out.println("server> we get signal.");                
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (str.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("server> everything is received.");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("server> got message: " + str);
        }
        System.out.println("server> done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for those points(clarified much). Now what if the client never sends a message to the server, will it keep waiting forever at line 15 until connection is closed ? Also what does flush() do ?

Comment: That's what a server does. It blocks on the server(or in some cases, busy loops) forever until there is somebody making a request. It does this over and over, and typically instead of handling it, creates a thread that does it for them. A typical server is very lazy, and its job is to acknowledge every single request that comes its way, which it often struggles with(imagine a million people trying to request a webpage all at once), hence it must be lazy).

Comment: Thanks alot. Everything makes much more sense now :D .

Comment: I made the program because I was as confused as you were regarding how TCP/IP worked, and wanted a very explicit self contained example. Hopefully it helps you fully grasp the general idea and get to applying it). Modern web servers are much more clever and do much more lazy nonblocking things. NodeJS does a great job teaching these techniques(at the cost of heavily discouraging people from trying it or understanding what it is), and provides the easiest way to set up a server  that I know of.

Comment: I wish comments let you have newlines in them to avoid walls of text.

Comment: Yea exactly. But there seems one problem, when I removed Line 3,4 and 5 from the client even then the server keeps on running and doesn't go into blocked state as mentioned above(and in accordance with my logic as well). The server lines 14-18 simply execute as if, the server was never waiting for a message from a client to unblock(4th point in the answer).

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 Check my response at the end of the post.

Comment: Thanks alot. So now what I've understood after some experimenting is that, the server will wait two times- 1. When accept() is called 2. When a inputStream is needed for some message from the client. In the 2nd case, if the client sends a message then the server resumes from wait and if the client doesn't send a message then the server waits for the client to terminate and the automatically unblocks and resumes. Is this how it works ?

Answer (score 1):

As Jose Luis said, server must have a properly configuration in order to be connected to a client,

> 11 --> 12 --> 13 --> 14 then 1--> 2--> 3--> 4--> 5

after this the server and the client can exchange information

take a look at this descriptive image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The client is pretty simple. It opens a socket to the server and writes to it.

The server is more complex. Line 12 creates the socket on the specified port. Line 13 will wait until a client connects to that port and sends a message. Then line 16-18 are fairly straightforward. They read the message from the socket (which was put there by the client) and print it out.

Comment: Thanks alot. What if I never send a message from the client to the server, will the server halt at line 15 ?

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 I'm pretty sure that's correct, but you can always try it out and see!

Comment: I tried it but sadly it seems that the server was never waiting for an output message from the client as all the statements in server executed even when I commented out lines 3, 4 and 5 from the client.